# Printing hex characters in c giving weird output

Tags: c, printf, scanf, hex

I have a network capture tool that captures packets and does some processing on them. Now, here is a small fragment of the code. `u_char` is the name given to `unsigned char`. When I try to print the variable `smac` to `stdout`, all I get is `000000000000` on the screen. I want to print the actual `smac` and `dmac`.

```
char * str;
char converted[6*2 + 1];
u_char smac[6], dmac[6];
int i;

if (ntop_lua_check(vm, __FUNCTION__, id, LUA_TSTRING)) 
  return(CONST_LUA_PARAM_ERROR);

if ((str = (char*)lua_tostring(vm, id)) == NULL)  
  return(CONST_LUA_PARAM_ERROR);

sscanf(str, "%hhx:%hhx:%hhx:%hhx:%hhx:%hhx",
       &smac[0], &smac[1], &smac[2], &smac[3], &smac[4], &smac[5]);

for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
  sprintf(&converted[i*2], "%02X", smac[i]);
}

printf("%s\n", converted);
```

Is the problem with unsigned char getting promoted to `int` or something by `sprintf` and printing the unnecessary two bytes? I am not sure.Any help would be of great value. Thank you.

Comment: How can you be getting `00:00:00:00:00:00` on the screen when your `sprintf` doesn't have a `:` in the format string?

Comment: Please — white space in your code is your friend.  That's unreadable as given!

Comment: Perhaps looking at `str` would shed some light on this?

Comment: @mbratch I'm Sorry!!! I just got 000000000000...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The all important lines are the ones with the scanf and sprintf and printf...

Comment: I slightly modified the code and added a string literal in place of `str` in the `sscanf`. It worked correctly. I agree with @alk, we need to know what `str` actually looks like.

Comment: Please add a `printf("str = <<%s>>\n", str);` before the call to `sscanf()`, and please check the return value from `sscanf()`.  For example: `if (sscanf(str, "...", &smac[1], ...) != 6) { ...report error... }`.

Comment: Are you sure `u_char` is `unsigned char`? I just tried a quick test and this works if `smac[]` is `unsigned char`. Are you sure `str` isn't `00:00:00:00:00:00`?

Comment: You should check the result of sscanf. It tells you how many matches were made or if an error occurred. If the result is not 6 then your input string is probably malformed.

Comment: Maybe an old compiler that does not understand `%hhx`?